# Ruby on Rails simple_form radio validates true but not false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have this field created with simple_form:

```
= f.input :is_private, label: false, :collection => [['Public', false ],['Private', true ]], :as => :radio_buttons
```

Here is my model validation:

```
validates :is_private, presence: {:message => "Please choose public or private."}
```

For some reason this field only validates when `Private` is selected but I'm really stumped as to why that could be. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`PresenceValidator`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4bbd05c90e5a62c0316307b3ca7c2262ed98b567/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb#L7) adds errors when values are `blank?`. When "Public" is selected, the value of `is_private` is set to `false`. Rails defines [`FalseClass#blank?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/126dc47665c65cd129967cbd8a5926dddd0aa514/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L64) to return true, which means it will fail the `PresenceValidator` validation.